# Como criar um pair de valores dentro de um Map em Java

Tags: java, hashmap, collection

É possível criar um `Map` em Java utilizando o conceito de `pair` que existe em C++? Tenho tentado usar da forma abaixo, porém, não consigo atribuir valores para o meu mapa.

```
Map<String, Entry<Entry<Integer,Integer>,String> > sub = new HashMap<>();
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Por incrível que pareça, que eu saiba até hoje não existe em Java uma estrutura de dados genérica capaz de armazenar um par de valores... >:( Mas segundo [essa resposta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16089354/520779) é possível sim usar `Map.Entry` para esse propósito - é só você instanciar uma de suas implementações concretas (`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` ou `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`) em vez da interface em si. Uma opção talvez mais amigável (se disponível) é o `javafx.util.Pair`

Comment: Boa ideia @mgibsonbr! Mto obrigado!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Java realmente não tem um `Pair` propriamente dito.

Você pode implementar sua própria classe que lide com o par de dados desejado. Normalmente esta classe é uma implementação da interface [`Map.Entry<K,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html). Um exemplo de implementação pode ser vista [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3110644/221800) no SO:

```
import java.util.Map;

final class MyEntry<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {
    private final K key;
    private V value;

    public MyEntry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public V setValue(V value) {
        V old = this.value;
        this.value = value;
        return old;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/MyEntry.java).

Claro que nada impede de criar uma classe que implemente o par como você desejar sem implementar esta interface.

Ou pode usar a [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html). Poderia usar assim:

```
Map<String, Map.Entry<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>, String>> sub = new HashMap<>();
```

Você teria que criar cada objeto destes, ir aninhando para colocar no mapa:

```
 Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> par1 = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(0, 1);
 Map.Entry<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>, String> par2 = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(par1, "txt");
 sub.put("chave", par2);
```

Comment: Agora entendi, dessa maneira vc abordou @bigown ficou bem clara! Desta maneira funcionou no meu código. Mto obrigado!

Comment: Não sei o quanto você conhece programação mas é bom deixar claro que eu criei variáveis intermediárias só para facilitar a visualização, você obviamente pode criar o objeto do par e usá-lo direto no mapa, como ocorre em (quase) toda linguagem.

Comment: Estou começando em Java não faz muito tempo, ainda estou me adaptando a linguagem. Esta parte de estrutura de dados ainda estou engatinhando, por isso estou cheio de dúvidas. Este trecho que vc mostrou, compilou no meu programa. Pode parecer boba minha pergunta agora, mas para eu acessar individualmente o valor da minha segunda String do Map sub, seria através de um iterator? Dessa maneira funciona? sub.values().iterator();

Comment: Nenhuma pergunta é boba, só existem perguntas mal feitas, que não é o caso da sua. Pergunta o que precisa aqui. Vai levar um tempo para você se adaptar à linguagem. Em geral não se usar iteradores em Java como no C++, eles até são usados mas é mais automático na maioria das situações. Isto já é uma outra pergunta mas o acesso básico acho que é `sub.get("chave").getValue()`. Não tenho certeza se é isto porque nunca usei. Não sei se esta forma que está tentando dá certo, mas duvido que ela seja a mais simples. Ou não entendi o que está querendo :)

Comment: A Apache disponibiliza no pacote `apache-lang` um utilitário pra isso, a classe [`Pair<L,R>`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html). Bem útil e preguiçoso quando se precisa retornar apenas 2 valores a partir de algum framework de consulta ao banco de dados, como o MyBatis. Por curiosidade, eles fornecem também a tripla. Tem outras bibliotecas que vi que fornecem até a 5-upla.

Comment: C# tem todos tipos de tuplas por referência e por valor, por isso não dá pra comparar as duas linguagens :D